# DC 12v 2a into DC 12v 3000aH

Tags: power-supply, power, dc

Now before you all call me a retard
Let me just state that I know nothing about the electrical world at all. 
But I need someone help me answer my question

So I have a TV that says on the back 'Input; DC 12v 3000aH'
and I have a power supply that says 'Output; DC 12v 2A'

Will that work? Or burn down my house?
(I assume 'aH' and 'A' means the same thing) My common sense tells me that the power supply should say 'Output; DC 12v 3A'
(Fyi i lost the original power supply for the TV) 
So I need to buy a new one

Much appreciate anyone who answers this

Comment: Mind if you just show a picture of the label on the TV?

Comment: A is not the same as Ah. On the other hand, aH is something I've never heard of. (Attohenry? Anyway, the capitalization matters.) Yes, a picture would probably help clear things up.

Comment: @Dampmaskin Sounds low! :-) 3000 aH is a modern CPU transistor-transistor interconnect amount of inductance.

Comment: I got confused. Tv says 12v 3a... power supply says 2000 mA. Sorry to all for the mix up. Here are the photos. Please let me know if this will be ok https://imgur.com/a/tHd88

Comment: Unlikely. 3000 mA = 3 A < 2 A. Your device may consume less than rated 3 A but your powersupply won't deliver more than 2 A.

Comment: Yeah, basically you just need to look for a supply that can supply 3A or more at 12V. Please read the answer linked to by Bryan Boettcher.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you decipher this, on a consumer product (which is almost always constant-voltage.)

**Voltage** -- in Volts, coded V - should match. 12V... 12V.... You're ok.

**Current (Amperage)** -- is measured in Amps, coded A.   Consumer products automatically draw as much current as they need, like a horse drinking as much water as it needs.  The device gives a worst case figure.  The supply must supply *at least that much*.

The TV wants 3A - that was easy.  The supply gives 2000mA... Now that's an oddly large number, isn't it?  Has everything to do with the "m", which is the SI symbol for "milli" or 1/1000.  Like milligrams and millilitres, you must divide by 1000, so 2A.    The supply can't give enough power to run the TV.  Fail.

**AC/DC** - the supply and appliance must match up on whether they use AC or DC.   The symbol for AC is a sinewave, DC is a solid line over a broken one (why???)

**If DC, polarity** -- in DC, it matters which is positive or negative, there's a little diagram showing whether the center contact is positive or negative.  These must match.

**Fit** - the connectors must fit, obviously.  *Physicaly fitting does not mean the voltages are compatible, there is no standard for that.*